# Pointer Array in C

Tags: c

I initial two dynamic-arrays

```
int *a = malloc(3 * sizeof(int)); 
int *b = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
```

Now I want when `*(b + 1)` change value, `*(a + 1)` will change too. But when `*b` and `*(b + 2)` change their values, `*a` and `*(a + 2)` have no effect. I mean:

```
*(b+1) = 5; // *(a+1) will equal 5
```

I tried

```
a + 1 = b + 1
```

Compiler announce error. Someone tells me somehow?

Comment: Why not just use a single pointer if you want them to be the same?

Comment: `*(b+1)` should have no impact on `*(a+1)`.  If it does, you've left out some pretty important pieces of code where you change what `a` and `b` are pointing at.

Comment: You'll need to write a function if you want that sort of logic.

Comment: If you want `*(b+1)` to affect `*(a+1)` like that, then replace `int *b = malloc(3*sizeof(int))` with `int *b = a` after initialising `a`.

Comment: `a` and `b` aren't "*pointer arrays*".

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.

The only thing you can do is to change `*(a+1)` every time you change `*(b+1)`. For example:

```
*(b+1) = 5;
*(a+1) = *(b+1);
// now *(a+1) and *(b+1) both contain 5.
```

or, as it is normally written:

```
b[1] = 5;
a[1] = b[1];
// now a[1] and b[1] both contain 5.
```

But I gather this is not what you want.

Comment: Same as `a[1] = b[1] = 5;`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making the arrays hidden and coding read and write functions.

```
#include "staticarrays.h" /* prototypes */

static int a[3], b[3];

int a_write(int index, int value) {
    a[index] = value;
    return value;
}
int b_write(int index, int value) {
    b[index] = value;
    if (index == 1) a[1] = value;
    return value;
}
int a_read(int index) {
    return a[index];
}
int b_read(int index) {
    return b[index];
}
```

And in another file use these functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "staticarrays.h"

int main(void) {
    b_write(1, 42); /* b[1] = 42; */
    printf("%d\n", a_read(1)); /* a[1] */
    return 0;
}
```